# Docker: How to use a Dockerfile in addition to docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am using this repo to set up a local wordpress development environment:
https://github.com/mjstealey/wordpress-nginx-docker#tldr

I hijacked the docker-compose to change the nginx port, but also to try to install openssl and vim on the nginx server.  But when I do a docker-compose up the nginx server never starts properly.

This is what i see:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
57cf3dff059f   nginx:latest           "bash"                   About a minute ago   Restarting (0) 14 seconds ago                            nginx
```

I tried to reference a Dockerfile inside the docker-compose like this:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:${NGINX_VERSION:-latest}
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - '8085:8085'
      - '443:443'
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_CONF_DIR:-./nginx}:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${NGINX_LOG_DIR:-./logs/nginx}:/var/log/nginx
      - ${WORDPRESS_DATA_DIR:-./wordpress}:/var/www/html
      - ${SSL_CERTS_DIR:-./certs}:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ${SSL_CERTS_DATA_DIR:-./certs-data}:/data/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    restart: always
```

Notice the line that says "build: .".
Here's the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update

# installing vim isn't necessary.  but just handy.
RUN apt-get -y install openssl
RUN apt-get -y install vim
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong.  Maybe I should be defining tasks directly in the docker-compose for the nginx server?
I wanted to find a way to make a clean separation between our customizations and the original code. But maybe this isn't possible.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

This is what the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN apt-get update
  && apt-get -y install openssl
  && apt-get -y install vim
```

And the nginx section of the docker-compose.yml:

```
  nginx:
    #image: nginx:${NGINX_VERSION:-latest}
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - '8085:8085'
      - '443:443'
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_CONF_DIR:-./nginx}:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${NGINX_LOG_DIR:-./logs/nginx}:/var/log/nginx
      - ${WORDPRESS_DATA_DIR:-./wordpress}:/var/www/html
      - ${SSL_CERTS_DIR:-./certs}:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ${SSL_CERTS_DATA_DIR:-./certs-data}:/data/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    restart: always
```

Comment: What is the exact command you're using for `docker build`? Are you seeing any errors when running `docker-compose up`?

Comment: When Nginx is running, how will it use `vim` or the `openssl` binary; can you use the unmodified `nginx` image?  If you do need these changes, you should try to install all packages in a single `apt-get install` command (which will be noticeably faster) and you should `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single command (to avoid layer-cache issues on rebuilds).

Comment: You should read *Using environment variables in nginx configuration (new in 1.19)* in [the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)

Comment: @code_monk - I'll take a look but i don't think that's the root cause of my problem?  Cuz ... without the build reference to my new Dockerfile, everything works as is using the latest nginx image....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you maybe need to change the base image that you are using in the docker file?:

```
FROM nginx:latest
```

Then in the docker file, because you are creating your own customised version of nginx image, you should either give custom name or tag.

Comment: In particular, do _not_ say `image: nginx` in the `docker-compose.yml` file; that will cause your local copy of the Docker Hub `nginx` image to be overwritten with your custom image.  If you're not planning to push the image to a repository it's safe to leave out the `image:` line entirely.

Comment: that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.  I still have the same behavior.   Please see Edit 1 in my post for details of what the files now look like.  Thanks!

Comment: Probably worth pulling the image again, because the combination of docker-composr and docker file in original question will most likely have overwritten the nginx file if I'm not mistaken

Comment: i blew away the nginx image and reran docker-compose up using the code that's shown in Edit 1.  It didn't download a new nginx image at all.

Comment: I was missing the trailing "\" on each line of the Dockerfile.  I fixed that syntax error and I also blew away the old nginx image.  Now it works and I have vim and openssl installed.  Thanks.